# Statistical model of a website

Tags: hidden-markov-model, natural-language, generative-models

I know that HMMs can be used to construct statistical models of text. Thus, we can generate text according to this model, and compute the likelihood of a text sample under the model.

What tools are used to construct statistical models of websites or webpages? Basically, it means things like various paragraphs, headings, links, pictures, menus on sidebars etc. or some subset of these features. Are there any generative models for webpages or websites?